# OS X: module not found - but works?

Tags: macos, pycharm

Faced with some odd behaviour in PyCharm on OS X:

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.5
BuildVersion:   14F1021
```

From Terminal - module found:

```
>>> import argparse
```

But - if I run "*Execute line in console*" about `import argparse` directly in PyCharm - I have:

```
>>> import argparse

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/PyCharm CE/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

It also highlighted in red in PyCharm - but works:

[image]

I have worked with PyCharm on Win and Linux boxes - and never seen such stuff there...

I guess - it is something about how PyCharm's modules search realised in Mac version.

Any tips how it can be fixed? It's annoying - have a lot of "errors" in view.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have selected your [Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) for your new project on this machine. The steps to do this on OSX aren't the same as Windows last time I checked, so it can be a little frustrating.

Otherwise, check your path:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

And make sure to check "[Add content roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-content-roots.html)" and "Add source roots" to path, if necessary in your configuration.